# Thread's DefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler not catching exception thrown in AlertDialog onClick() method

Tags: java, android, exception, uncaught-exception, uncaughtexceptionhandler

I set a default `UncaughtExceptionHandler` for the current thread in my `Activity`'s `onCreate()` and throw a `RunTimeException` from my `AlertDialog`'s `onClick()` listener but the exception is not caught. I also tried throwing the exception from `onCreateOptionsMenu()` and `onOptionsItemSelected()` and it wasn't caught. It is caught however when thrown from `onCreate()` or `onResume()`.

Here's my activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new DefExcHandler());
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: "+Thread.currentThread().getName()+" "+Thread.currentThread().getId());

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setNeutralButton("CRASH", this);
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        Log.d(TAG, "onClick: "+Thread.currentThread().getName()+" "+Thread.currentThread().getId());
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

And here's my exception handler:

```
public class DefExcHandler implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {

    private static final String TAG = "DefExcHandler";

    public DefExcHandler() {
        Log.d(TAG, "DefaultExceptionHandler: ");
    }

    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Uncaught exception caught: "+ex.getMessage()+" "+ex.getCause().toString());
    }
}
```

Based on the log messages I make in my activity the thread is the same when in `onCreate()` and `onClick()`:

```
09-27 15:00:57.260 10667-10667/a.b.c D/MainActivity: onCreate: main 1
09-27 15:01:52.680 10667-10667/a.b.c D/MainActivity: onClick: main 1
```

Why is the exception not caught when thrown from `onClick()`, `onCreateOptionsMenu()` or `onOptionsItemSelected()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to reproduce the application's behavior. The `DefExcHandler` instance seems to be missed since it isn't logging anything, but I tried two other things that worked: breakpoint and file creation.

Please try to set a breakpoint inside `uncaughtException()`. I believe it will stop the execution in your code. And I have written an example below that uses a file as a flag to indicate that the uncaught exception handler is really being invoked.

In sum, it seems that `DefExcHandler.uncaughtException()` is being called but Android can't do the logging for some unknown reason, maybe an internal race condition.

```java
// Example that assures that an UncaughtExceptionHandler
// is being invoked by flagging execution with file creation.

public class MainActivity extends ... implements ... {

    private File mCrashFile;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mCrashFile = new File(getFilesDir(), "crash");

        // Crash file existence means the application has crashed before.
        Log.d(TAG, "crash file exists: " + mCrashFile.exists());

        // Clear crash flag.
        if (mCrashFile.exists()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "crash file delete: " + mCrashFile.delete());
        }

        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new DefExcHandler());

        ...

    }

    private class DefExcHandler implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {

        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {

            // Set crash flag.
            try {
                mCrashFile.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // dunno if it really prints anything
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Log messages indeed caused the problem. Very strange behaviour